# Is it documented exactly which i7 is in the mac mini late 2012?

Tags: hardware, mac-mini

They have announced a number of different CPU options for the late 2012 mac mini.  I'm interested in the 2.6 Ghz Quad-Core i7.  Should I assume that's the i7-3720QM processor? Is there an official document that I missed that details this.

Comment: Generally, Apple doesn't provide that level of detail in marketing but that people will document what is in the models after they start arriving. I'll keep my eyes peeled for an authoritative review covering the Mac mini. If I'm buying, I've also asked my Apple sales contact to find out if it really matters (buying several for a render farm, etc...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no public Apple document that has this info. But, with a little bit of info from Intels' CPU specs site, you can assume that's the one.

There are sites which show you that info also (to see if your assumption was good):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini#Specifications_3

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/index-macmini.html

According to the EveryMac site, the 2012 Mac Mini use the following chips:

- 2.5 GHz Core i5 (I5-3210M)
- 2.3 GHz Core i7 (I7-3615QM)
- 2.6 GHz Core i7 (I7-3720QM)